# Create symlinks with lowercase names from uppercase files and directories

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I have a directory that contains files and folders with names that contain uppercase letters.
I was wondering if it's possible using `bash` to create symlinks with the same name but in lowercase.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       570 Sep 22 00:00 AiA_SA_2014_08_10
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       575 Sep 12 00:00 AiA_SA_Lite_2014_09_07
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       570 Sep 22 00:00 AiA_SA_2014_08_10
```

to

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       570 Sep 22 00:00 AiA_SA_2014_08_10
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         x Sep 22 00:00 aia_sa_2014_08_10-> AiA_SA_2014_08_10
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       575 Sep 12 00:00 AiA_SA_Lite_2014_09_07
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         x Sep 12 00:00 aia_sa_lite_2014_09_07 -> AiA_SA_Lite_2014_09_07
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       570 Sep 22 00:00 AiA_SA_2014_08_10
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         x Sep 22 00:00 aia_sa_2014_08_10 -> AiA_SA_2014_08_10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In recent bashes, you can use the `,,` parameter expansion to turn a string to lowercase:

```
shopt -s extglob
for file in *?([:upper:])* ; do
    ln -s "$file" "${file,,}"
done
```

The extglob pattern only selects files with an uppercase letter in their names.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.

Using a simple loop:

```
for i in *; do 
  [[ -f $i ]] || continue # in case of empty directory
  lcname=${i,,} # Covert the name to lowercase
  ln -s "$i" "$lcname"
done
```

If you are not running from current directory, you can give fullpath in `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
declare -l lower
for upper in *; do lower="$upper"; ln -s "$upper" "$lower"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
parallel ln -s {} '{=$_=lc($_)=}'  ::: *
```